# Get all Facebook posts of user wall

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm using the Facebook php sdk to try to get posts of a users wall.

When I use the following code I only get some reaction on events and some mentions, but but not the messages, photos's etc. I actually posted on my wall?

What can be the problem?

```
$result = $facebook->api('/me/feed/',array('access_token' => $facebook->access_token,'limit'=>100));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you authenticating and what permissions are you asking for in your `access_token`? If you aren't authenticating your user, you'll be limited to `public` posts only. You also need to make sure you request `read_stream` permission when you authenticate your user.